# How to determine largest individual value in excel in a group of identical cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, macros, spreadsheet

I am trying to figure out Column D Which SKU has highest total? how do I do that in excel with a formula? In this case I determined it manually, I tried IF=IF(A2=A3,IF(C2>C3,"Largest","NOT Largest")) that sort of worked but in instances where there are more than 2 identical group SKU's it would show more than one as the highest total, for example it would show B and C as the highest rather than just C. Better yet just sort column C in order highest first but keeping column a grouped as well.

```
GroupSKU    Individual SKU  Individual SKU Total    Which Individual SKU Has  Highest Total?
ABC             A                 1                              C
ABC             B                 2                              C
ABC             C                 3                              C
DEF             D                 5                              F
DEF             E                 6                              F
DEF             F                 8                              F
GHI             G                 3                              G
GHI             H                 2                              G
GHI             I                 1                              G
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Better yet just sort column C in order highest first but keeping
>   column a grouped as well.

Sort > Custom Sort > Sort by column A, then by column C

Comment: Until you pointed that out I didnt even realize you can add levels, thanks so much I answered my own question and you made me realize the solution. Thanks